# Are these all valid alternatives to "I'm not a picky eater"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm not picky about the foods that I eat.

> 1. There are not many foods that I don't like to eat.
> 2. I don't have many foods I don't like to eat.
> 3. There are few foods I don't like to eat.

Here, I'd like to know if I can use all of them without making big difference. Last but not least, I'd like to know if #4 is natural.

> 4. I eat most of the foods that I can get a chance to eat. If I had a chance to eat something new that I haven't eaten, I would eat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the three you listed are correct, but I would consider the first to be clearest.

The fourth just needs some minor adjustments:

> I eat most <strike>of the</strike> foods that I can get a chance to (eat). If I had a chance to eat something new <strike>that I haven't eaten</strike>, I would (eat it).

- *...of the...* is not required
- *...that I haven't eaten...* is redundant

Or you could say the following instead of *...eat something new*:

> If I had a chance to eat something **that I haven't (eaten) before**...

- Bracketed words/phrases are not necessary and are a matter of preference.